# Quarkus Kafka kafka-quickstart QuoteProcessorTest.java returns No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers

Tags: java, apache-kafka, quarkus

I try the code delivered with "quarkus-quickstarts"/"kafka-quickstart" and get this error message:

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers

For the [QuoteProcessorTest.java](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/main/kafka-quickstart/processor/src/test/java/org/acme/kafka/processor/QuoteProcessorTest.java)  class.

I'm wondering since the code is delivered by quarkus so I expect it to work without any errors.

Comment: You need to provide more details about where Kafka is running and how you're running the code. Maybe there's a bug? What debugging have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the README, the code is intended to run with a pre-installed Kafka broker, such as one provided by Docker Compose - https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/main/kafka-quickstart/docker-compose.yaml

The tests themselves do not appear to be using any mocked / local broker, so you may need to start Kafka on your own, or skip the tests when building the project

Or if you used the `quarkus:dev` commands listed, it says Kafka should start automatically